# Why can't I say 'I am much happy now'?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, comparative-constructions

As far as I know, to use "much" with an adjective, the adjective has to be in comparative form. For example, much happier, much prettier, etc.

And it is used with nouns;

- I don't have much time.
- I didn't get much sleep last night

And as a pronoun;

I don't talk to her much (often)

With positive adjectives we use "very" for similar meaning.

For example,

- I'm very happy now.

What would "I am much happy", "I am much beautiful", "I am much good" mean?

Comment: *I am much shorter than you.* That's using *much* with an adjective. So, am I missing something? Or *I have much happiness*. That's not comparative in any way. (It's nonstandard but still grammatical.)

Comment: Colleen V, I edited my question, Please re-enable it

Comment: Thanks for adding more information. If you want to make sure I see your message, you need to put an @ in front of my username and not put any spaces in it, like `@ColleenV`

Comment: "I am much happy", "I am much beautiful", and "I am much good" would all mean bad grammar. Why? You seem to know the rules. Use a comparative adjective form with much: much happier, much better, etc. BTW, in "I don't talk to her much" "much" is not used with a noun. This "much" is different from "much" in "I don't have much time." They perform different functions. This may help - https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/much_1

Comment: I've put more elaboration. Is it okay now?

Comment: btw can I use much to mean often here.  I don't feel good much(often)

Comment: If you use much *after* the adjective or verb, it can take the meaning of *often*. It can still take the meaning of degree, though. "I don't walk there much" has to be to do with frequency, because you can't apply that sort of adverb of degree to *to walk* , but "I don't like it much" will be read as degree, because talking about frequency would be hard with *to like*. "I don't enjoy it much" could mean either, but will usually be to do with degree rather than frequency.

Comment: but why does *I don't feel good much* sound awkward to me? 

Comment: @SamBC ......

Comment: It's just randomly not very idiomatic. Sometimes to analyse it you would need to do a deep study of the history of how language is used. "I don't feel good **that** much" is fine.

Comment: yeah but that much is an intensity. It never means often. Yeah you're right sometimes things are grammatically correct but not idiomatic

Answer (score 2):

***Much*** can be used with an adjective or with a noun. To be used with an adjective, the adjective has to be *comparative*, such as ***happier*** or ***shorter***. To be used with a noun, it must be a mass noun (uncountable), such as ***happiness***. So, we can say:

> I am much happier.

Or:

> I have much happiness.

(It doesn't work with all mass nouns in all situations; native speakers don't say "with much speed", because we tend to think of speed as having size rather than quantity - so it's "with great speed". But we might still say "without much speed", and "without great speed" would sound a little stilted. Even with *happiness* I would tend to use *great*, and I think other native speakers would tend to as well, but *much* doesn't seem as unnatural with *happiness* as it does with *speed*. Trying to break this down to get a clear idea of when to use it with what would be rather a mammoth task.)

"I am much happy" doesn't mean anything except someone who doesn't know English very well is trying to say either "much happier" or "very happy". It has no special or unique meaning, it's just something that would be pretty much universally seen as **wrong**.

Comment: could you provide more examples of uncountable nouns which can't be used with much?

Comment: It's not even "can't be used with much"; it depends on other words. Like "without much speed" is fine. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: okay I get it. Thanks for the elaboration